# Show alert on input change in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

How can i display a confirmation alert only if i want to change radio button on previous step? So if i confirm my action all steps below should be removed.
I've binded a @change directive to the radio button with a method implementing the expected confirmation alert, but it appears on each change i make.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p0aLt8f2/)

Thanks for your advices in advance

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      answer: ["1"],
      stepsData: [
        {
          id: "1",
          yes_section: "2",
          no_section: "4",
          name: "Step 1",
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          yes_section: "5",
          no_section: "1",
          name: "Step 2",
        },
        {
          id: "3",
          yes_section: "2",
          no_section: "4",
          name: "Step 3",
        },
        {
          id: "4",
          yes_section: "2",
          no_section: "4",
          name: "Step 4",
        },
        {
          id: "5",
          yes_section: "2",
          no_section: "4",
          name: "Step 5",
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    quation() {
      return this.answer.map((answer) => {
        return this.stepsData.find((step) => step.id === answer);
      });
    },
  },
  methods: {
    pushAnswer(answer) {
      this.answer.push(answer);
    },
    confirmPopup() {
        alert('Are you sure?')
    },
  },
});
```

```css
.step {
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div v-for="(step, id) in quation" :key="id" class="step">
      <div v-html="step.name"></div>
      <div>
        <input
          type="radio"
          :id="step.UF_NO_SECTION"
          :name="step.ID"
          :value="step.yes_section"
          @click="pushAnswer(step.yes_section)"
          @change="confirmPopup"
        />
        <label
          :for="step.UF_NO_SECTION"
          class="legal-aid__step-btn button _outline _no"
         >
          YES {{ step.yes_section }}
        </label>
      </div>
       <div class="legal-aid__step-action_no">
        <input
           type="radio"
           :id="step.UF_NO_SECTION"
           :name="step.ID"
           :value="step.no_section"
           @click="pushAnswer(step.no_section)"
           @change="confirmPopup"
         />
         <label
           :for="step.UF_NO_SECTION"
           class="legal-aid__step-btn button _outline _no"
         >
          NO {{ step.no_section }}
         </label>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain better what you want to achieve? your question is not very clear.

Comment: Regarding to your usage of `@change` it acts as it should - it calls the `confirmPopup` method any time the input has changed.

Comment: @NoyGafni hey! I'll try to explain. Initially block "Step 1" is always visible. When i select radio "Yes" or "No" step 2 appears (with data depending on selected radio value) and so on. But if i want to go back to step 1 for example and change selected radio, confirmation alert should appear - that's when confirmPopup method should be called

Comment: I posted a answer, and I recommend you edit the question as well so it will be clearer

Answer (score 0):

I would add a property on every `stepData` that is called `isSelected` which will be initialized to `false` and once it was clicked, it will be changed to `true`.

So you data will look like this:

```js
stepsData: [
        {
          id: "1",
          yes_section: "2",
          no_section: "4",
          name: "Step 1",
          isSelected: false
        },
   ....
]
```

You will need to change `pushAnswer` to set `isSelected` to `true:

```js
@click="pushAnswer(step)"
```

```js
pushAnswer(answer) {
      answer.isSelected = true;
      this.answer.push(answer.yes_section);
    },
```

And `confirmPopup` function will check if the answer is already selcted or not:

```js
@change="confirmPopup(step)"
```

```js
confirmPopup(step) {
        if (step.isSelected) {
           alert('Are you sure?')
        }
    },
```

Of course you can change anything to your liking, but this is the basic idea